# Pre-filling search query's. POST Http

Tags: google-chrome, http, url, post, get

I'm trying to understand how to use query strings in URL's and trying to make some shortcuts to make my job easier. From what I've been reading here and there there are ways to pre-program a website using query parameters. I went to the website I'm interested and pulled the "search form" part that I would like to pre-fill (this is a database search, I would like to have a direct link that just pre-populates and just shows the results of the search instead of me filling it each time I look for new data).
This is from the website's "inspect source". the  part of it:

```
<form id="partInquiry" name="partInquiry" action="PartInquiryForEdit.htm" method="post">
        <table style="width: 40%">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="left"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="ez1">
                <td class="label">Search By:
                </td>
                <td class="input"><select id="searchby" name="search">
                        <option value="part_number">Part Number</option><option value="part_description">Part Description</option><option value="rdo_gpl">RDO/GPL</option><option value="rdo_productCd">RDO/Product Code</option>
                    </select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="ez1">
                <td class="label">Match By:
                </td>
                <td class="input"><select id="matchby" name="match">
                        <option value="matches">Exactly Matches</option><option value="contains">Contains</option><option value="startsWith">Starts With</option><option value="endsWith">Ends With</option>
                    </select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="ez1">
                <td class="label">Search For:
                </td>
                <td class="input"><input id="searchfor" name="searchString" type="text" value="" maxlength="750"/> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="ez1">
                <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" onclick="clearSession();"
                    value="Submit"
                    class="Button" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="submit"
                    value="Cancel"
                    class="Button" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <BR>
        <BR>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><label class="errorBox" id="errorBox"></label> 
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table> <input type="hidden" id="rowsToAdd" name="rowsToAdd" /> <input
                    type="hidden" id="rowsToRemove" name="rowsToRemove" /> <input
                    type="hidden" id="rowsToSubmit" name="rowsToSubmit" /> <input
                    type="hidden" id="isExport" name="isExport" /> 
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table> </td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>



        <BR>
        <BR>
    </form>
```

I tried the following to no avail and I dont know how else to do it:

```
?search=part_description&searchby=part_description&matchby=contains&match=contains&searchfor=MYSEARCHSTRING&searchString=MYSEARCHSTRING&Submit
?search=part_description&match=matches&searchString=MYSEARCHSTRING&Submit&submit
?searchby=part_description&matchby=matches&searchfor=MYSEARCHSTRING
```

I'm not sure I'm understanding how to do this or if maybe there's somewhere in the code where It disables this (and how would I find it?). As shown, I tried using the "names" but nothing, I also tried using the "id"s but nothign either. Also I dont know how to actually "submit" the search since the submit button has no id or name. only an "onclick" and a "value".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pre-populating a form via the query string is something that the website must explicitly support, it's not a general feature.  The website must be coded to accept values on the query string and then return the appropriate HTML to pre-select those values.

If the website does not support this, then what you can do as an alternative is create a [bookmarklet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) that populates the fields you want. For example:

```
javascript:var id=document.getElementById.bind(document);id('searchby').value='part_description';id('matchby').value='matches';id('searchfor')='MYSEARCHSTRING';void 0;
```

After you've loaded the site, you can click the bookmark to pre-fill the form.

Comment: Thank you. Two questions: How do I know if the website is coded to accept this? is there a code snippet im looking for? Second, the Bookmarklet would be local to me, myself and I right? (I was thinking of sharing these pre-filled URLS with other co-workers and use auto-hotkey to create shortcuts.

Comment: @dvd.Void Any code related to such a feature would be server-side and thus unknowable to you. So without finding an example where the website uses such a pre-filling feature, there is no way for you to know whether it exists or doesn't. As for the bookmarklets, each co-worker would have to setup the bookmarklet in the browser separately.

Comment: Ok thank you. Can I ask however, is the "code" (or query info) I wrote up there correct? If it is correct then I can safely assume that the website doesnt allow, otherwise it is unknown and maybe I'm just requesting it incorrectly.

Comment: If such a feature exists, one could reasonable assume the query parameters would match the field names, ie `?search=part_description&match=contains`.  It's technically possible they used different parameter names but it seems unlikely and there's no way to know for certain.